# push and splice values of array based on checkbox check and uncheck

Tags: jquery, arrays

Below is my checkbox

```
"<input type='checkbox' name='documents' value='" + item.ID + "' id='chkSelect_" + counter + "' onclick='getSelectedChk(this.value, this.id, \"" + item.NameOfDocument + "\", \"" + item.ApprovalStatus + "\", \"" + item.SelfAttested + "\",\"" + item.MIME + "\")' >" +
```

I wrote this in ajax success callback, onclick of this checkbox below function is called

```
var selected = [];
var selectedItemsToDelete = [];
var selectedItemsToCopy = [];
var selectedItemsToPreview = [];
var selectedItemsToDownload = [];
var selectedItemsToShare = [];
var selectedItemsToEsign = [];
var selectedCheckBoxes;
var selectedDocType;
var loadedResults;
var called;

function getSelectedChk(val, id, doc, stat,SelfAttested,MIME){
if ($("#"+id).is(":checked")) {
   selected.push(val);
   selectedItemsToDelete.push({"ID":val, "NameOfDocument": doc, "ApprovalStatus": stat});
   selectedItemsToCopy.push({"ID":val});
   selectedItemsToPreview.push({"ID":val, "NameOfDocument": doc});
   selectedItemsToDownload.push({"ID":val});
   selectedItemsToShare.push({"ID":val, "NameOfDocument": doc, "ApprovalStatus": stat});
  selectedItemsToEsign.push({"ID": val, "NameOfDocument": doc, "ApprovalStatus": stat, "SelfAttested": SelfAttested, "MIME":MIME});
}
else if(!$("#"+id).is(':checked')){
    selected.splice( $.inArray(val, selected), 1 );
    selectedItemsToDelete.splice( $.inArray({"ID":val, "NameOfDocument": doc, "ApprovalStatus": stat}, selectedItemsToDelete), 1 );
    selectedItemsToCopy.splice( $.inArray({"ID":val}, selectedItemsToCopy), 1 );
    selectedItemsToPreview.splice( $.inArray({"ID":val, "NameOfDocument": doc}, selectedItemsToPreview), 1 );       
    selectedItemsToDownload.splice( $.inArray({"ID":val}, selectedItemsToDownload), 1 );
    selectedItemsToShare.splice( $.inArray({"ID":val, "NameOfDocument": doc, "ApprovalStatus": stat}, selectedItemsToShare), 1 );
    selectedItemsToEsign.splice( $.inArray({"ID": val, "NameOfDocument": doc, "ApprovalStatus": stat, "SelfAttested": SelfAttested, "MIME":MIME}, selectedItemsToEsign), 1 );
}  
}
```

Here, when I am unchecking the checkbox, value is being spliced correctly only if I check and uncheck the same checkbox. If I check all checkboxes and uncheck a random checkbox from checked checkboxes, it is splicing the latest pushed value from array instead of splicing the unchecking checkbox's value.

What kind of condition can I write in my function to achieve this.

Comment: Please share a fiddle of what you have done

Comment: I think the question is fair enough to understand what I have done